# How do I set the visibility of a text box in SSRS using an expression?

Tags: reporting-services

I have a subtotal field for a calculated column that I want to hide when my report has not run yet, because on days with no data, it shows up as `NaN` on the report.

I have tried two methods, but neither are working. I just don't know what is wrong with the expression.

I tried hiding if my dataset had no rows:

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData")=0),False,True)
```

I also tried making a calculation:

```
=iif((fields!Scans.Value / fields!numberOfCases.Value) = 0, False, True)
```

I also tried checking `isnothing` on one of the columns in the calculation

```
=iif(IsNothing(fields!Scans.Value), False, True)
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This didn't work

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData") = 0),False,True)
```

but this did and I can't really explain why

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData") < 1),False,True)
```

guess SSRS doesn't like equal comparisons as much as less than.

Comment: If the data type of that field is something like a `float`, it'll probably never be exactly zero. If you are using float: stop it now.

Answer (score 68):

I tried the example that you have provided and the only difference is that you have True and False values switched as [bdparrish pointed out](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279704/how-do-i-set-the-visibility-of-a-text-box-in-ssrs-using-an-expression/6279937#6279937). Here is a working example of making an SSRS Texbox visible or hidden based on the number of rows present in a dataset.

**Step-by-step process:** **SSRS 2008 R2**

1. In this example, the report has a dataset named `Items` and has textbox to show row counts. It also has another textbox which will be visible only if the dataset Items has rows.
2. Right-click on the textbox that should be visible/hidden based on an expression and select "Text Box Properties...". Refer to screenshot #**1**.
3. On the Text Box Properties" dialog, click on "Visibility" from the left section. Refer to screenshot #**2**.
4. Select "Show or hide based on an expression".
5. Click on the expression button <kbd>fx</kbd>.
6. Enter the expression `=IIf(CountRows("Items") = 0 , True, False)`. Note that this expression is to **hide** the Textbox (**Hidden**).
7. Click OK twice to close the dialogs.
8. Screenshot #**3** shows data in the SQL Server table `dbo.Items`, which is the source for the report dataset `Items`. The table contains **3 rows**. Screenshot #**4** shows the sample report execution against the data.
9. Screenshot #**5** shows data in the SQL Server table `dbo.Items`, which is the source for the report data set `Items`. The table contains **no data**. Screenshot #**6** shows the sample report execution against the data.

**Screenshot #1:**

[image: 1]

**Screenshot #2:**

[image: 2]

**Screenshot #3:**

[image: 3]

**Screenshot #4:**

[image: 4]

**Screenshot #5:**

[image: 5]

**Screenshot #6:**

[image: 6]

Comment: I get the following error:-
Error 1 [rsInvalidAggregateScope] The Hidden expression for the text box ‘Textbox14’ has a scope parameter that is not valid for an aggregate function.  The scope parameter must be set to a string constant that is equal to either the name of a containing group, the name of a containing data region, or the name of a dataset.

Answer (score 16):

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData")=0),False,True)
```

Should be replaced with

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData")=0),True,False)
```

because the *Visibility* expression sets up the Hidden value.

Answer (score 7):

instead of this

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData")=0),False,True)
```

write only the expression when you want to hide

```
CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData")=0
```

or change the order of true and false places as below

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData")=0),True,False)
```

because the Visibility expression set up the Hidden value. that you can find above the text area as

```
" Set expression for: Hidden "
```

Answer (score 0):

Switch your false and true returns?  I think if you put those as a function in the visibility area, then false will show it and true will not show it.

Answer (score 0):

Visibility of the text box depends on the Hidden Value

As per the below example, if the internal condition satisfies then text box Hidden functionality will be True else if the condition fails then text box Hidden functionality will be False

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData") = 0), True, False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Twood, Visibility expression is the expressions you write on how you want the "visibility" to behave. So, if you would want to hide or show the textbox, you want to write this:

```
=IIf((CountRows("ScannerStatisticsData")=0),True,False)
```

This means, if the dataset is 0, you want to hide the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

the rdl file content:

```
<Visibility><Hidden>=Parameters!casetype.Value=300</Hidden></Visibility>
```

so the text box will hidden, if your expression is true.