# Hide a field/paramater in SSRS

Tags: sql, ssrs-2008, show-hide

Is it possible to hide a field in a SQL 2008 Report, based on the value of a parameter? I'm leaning towards a custom application and if push comes to shove I'll have do manually code each piece, but I would like to leverage SSRS as much as possible. I've included a screen shot of the report before it is populated. The area in red is what I would like to hide say, =iif(X=1,true,false)

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Set up the Expression In Text box Property >> Visibility >> Show or Hide on axpression.

```
=iif(X=1,true,false)
```

Hope this help..

[Look for the screen shot and more detail click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279704/how-do-i-set-the-visibility-of-a-text-box-in-ssrs-using-an-expression)

using SSRS manager, Parameter field cannot hide programtically. but you can create asp.net webform with SSRS report. [MSDN link](http://forums.asp.net/t/1281716.aspx)

Comment: Hiten004, I think I may have phrased it wrong. I would like to hide the field parameters, before the report itself populates. I've included a screen shot of the area I would like to programtically hide. The area in red is what I would like to hide, say =iif(X=1,true,false).

Comment: please check this [link](http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=101029) www.sqlteam.com.

Comment: @Hiten004 your link says "chick here". i clicked it, but didnt see any chicks!

Comment: @Артём Царионов my apologies. its fixed now

Comment: @Hiten004 i still dont see any chicks there!

Comment: here is your wish sir.. [chick here](http://services.flikie.com/view/v3/android/wallpapers/33559058)

Comment: I ended up making a custom web app with asp.net / Not really what I wanted but it gets the job done!