# Dynamically Move Content in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services

How do I dynamically show and hide text boxes in a SSRS report while maintaining proper alignment relative to my text boxes? I am using version 2005 btw.

I am not able to deviate from the specifications for this report because it is a legal document that will be given to individuals when they purchase or sell property.

I am interning as a software developer at a mortgage brokerage company. The report I am working on is a Buyer and Seller statement, which potentially needs multiple signatures. I need to dynamically add a space for each signature followed by the buyer or sellers name. This is tricky because there is additional content below the signature section that needs to be pushed down depending on how much space the signature section takes up.

Thank you guys! I use this site all the time while at work. I couldn't do my job without it!

Answer (score 0):

[This link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279704/how-do-i-set-the-visibility-of-a-text-box-in-ssrs-using-an-expression)

Answer for your question. In simple terms, by selecting the textbox control on the layout and pressing F4 will get you the properties dialog box. You can choose the visibility propery and write a ssrs expression within if condition, to toggle the visibility of the textbox based on the condition success or failure.

Comment: I was under the impression that doing this would hide the text box but it would not push the content that is below the invisible text box depending on the visibility of the text box. I will try this tomorrow morning. Thank you very much and sorry for asking a question that I should have probably found on my own.