# Productname on inventoryValueReport

Tags: microsoft-dynamics, dynamics-ax-2012

I am new to AX2012 and need to add product names to the InventoryValueReport in ax2012. I am trying to use a checkbox on the setup form but I'm just not sure at how to code the method to display the names on the report when the box is checked. Can anyone assist me?

Answer (score 0):

If the ssrs report layout will support it you can set the visibility of a column based on an expression based on the added parameter.

Steps: 
( [How do I set the visibility of a text box in SSRS using an expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279704/how-do-i-set-the-visibility-of-a-text-box-in-ssrs-using-an-expression) )

1. In this example, the report has a dataset named Items and has textbox to show row counts. It also has another textbox which will be visible only if the dataset Items has rows.
2. Right-click on the textbox that should be visible/hidden based on an expression and select Text Box Properties.... Refer screenshot #1.
3. On the Text Box Properties dialog, click on Visibility from the left section. Refer screenshot #2.
4. Select Show or hide based on an epxression.
5. Click on the expression button fx.