# Or function in Reportbuilder-expression doesn't work

Tags: reporting-services, vbscript, reportbuilder3.0

I'm making a report in Reportbuilder 2012 and I'm adding an expression to hide a certain field if it has no input. If I add the following expression it works perfectly

```
=(CountRows("WorkDataSetsFromSegReqId")=0)
```

But now I want it to be hidden when it has no input or when it's a certain Report Type, 'Register Date' in this case. I enter the following expression and now it suddenly starts showing up even if it has no input.

```
=(CountRows("WorkDataSetsFromSegReqId")=0) 
Or (Fields!WDS_ReportType.Value = Parameters!ReportType_RegisterDate.Value)
```

I've also tried it with an IIF statement but this gives me the same problem

```
=IIF(((CountRows("WorkDataSetsFromSegReqId") = 0) Or
(Fields!WDS_ReportType.Value = Parameters!ReportType_RegisterDate.Value)), True, False)
```

What is wrong with my expression?

Comment: You could try `CountRows("WorkDataSetsFromSegReqId")<1`, it sounds strange but I've seen this happen before.

Comment: I don't think that's going to solve my problem with the OR clause? :)

Comment: I've seen otherwise [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279704/how-do-i-set-the-visibility-of-a-text-box-in-ssrs-using-an-expression) :)

Comment: I've tried it, still the same issue.

Comment: Check the value of your parameters at runtime (i.e. what do `Fields!WDS_ReportType.Value` and `Parameters!ReportType_RegisterDate.Value` equate to?  The syntax for your above effort looks correct; first step is to verify that these are indeed equal.  Try replacing the `Parameters...` with the hardcoded text and see if that works?

Comment: If I hardcode it, it works. But it should be the exact same so I can't quite figure out what the problem is/was.

Comment: Are you placing the above expression inside a tablix that uses `WorkDataSetsFromSegReqId` dataset?

Comment: Yes I do, why? Is this not correct?

Comment: No, it is correct. In that case put the expression `Fields!WDS_ReportType.Value = Parameters!ReportType_RegisterDate.Value` in a cell not in the hidden property but in the cell value, this will show FALSE or TRUE based on the field and parameter data. It will let you debug the issue better.

Comment: If you hardcode it and it works, then replace it with the parameterised value and it doesn't, it suggests that your parameterised value isn't quite what you think it is.  Try outputting the parameterised value somewhere you can see it, and surround it with `'` characters (single quotes) - perhaps it has a trailing space causing the match to fail?

Comment: Have you tried using `=Or(CountRows("WorkDataSetsFromSegReqId")=0;Fields!WDS_ReportType.Value = Parameters!ReportType_RegisterDate.Value)`? This should return `True` if any of the arguments result in `True`. I believe that is what you are trying to accomplish, right?

Comment: Hi Victor. When I try to enter your suggestion it gives me the following error: _System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: The Visibility.Hidden expression for the tablix ‘Tablix1’ contains an error: [BC30201] Expression expected)_

Comment: @Dave, when I try this =IIf(First(Fields!WDS_ReportType.Value, "WorkDataSetsFromSegReqId")=Parameters!ReportType_RegisterDate.Value, True, False) it returns me True so I'm really not sure what's wrong...