# Hiding Header Text boxes based on Matix in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, matrix, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

I want to Hide my Header Text boxes based on the matrix. How can I set the expression in visibility setting?

[image]

Comment: Have you tried this? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279704/how-do-i-set-the-visibility-of-a-text-box-in-ssrs-using-an-expression

Comment: @DenStudent The link is useful but doesn't meet my requirement. My problem here is **how to get count for Matrix column lines?** if I want to apply the solution from that link.

Answer (score 0):

Goto the prepertied of the text box and then goto Visibility.
Select "Show or hide based on expression" and click on the [fx] button.

Assuming you wantt o show or hide depending if the Matrix is empty or not

Then enter the below:
=iif(CountRows("NameOfTheDataseOfTheMatrix") < 1,True, False)