# How to show one subreport at a time in Reporting Services

Tags: variables, reporting-services, visibility, subreport

I have 4 Stored Procedures, each with a single int parameter N.
The first one returns the "main interesting data" while the other 3 return some more data that are not as crucial.

1) I need a single report with a single Numeric parameter that, at first visualization, shows the data from the first Sproc.
Then, if I "do something", the first Table disappears and a second table appears with the data from the 2nd Stored. Same thing with the other 2 Stored: only ONE of the 4 tablix is visible at each given time.

2) Say the first Stored is definitely faster than the other three: I would like the first one to be called immediately after inserting the parameter N and the data to be shown as soon as they are retrieved. Only at this moment, just to save some time, I would like the other 3 Stored to be called while the user is still taking a look at the first query. The best would be that data are refreshed only when I go back to visualize the first Query, at which moment I load the data from all 4 Stored.

I am trying to do this with Subreports. So I have a main report with the first Stored shown in a tablix and I already have other 3 Reports that call the other Stored. I put 3 SubReport, each visualizing the data from one of the last three Stored. I set the visibility of the first to Show, the visibility of all the others to Hide and I connect the visibility of the reports with the option "Display can be toggled by this report time" to one each of three TEXTs I added as if they were buttons.
Problem is, in this way when I click on of these Texts, the related SubReport is shown but the previous one is not hidden. I would like the three Tablix to be superimposed and with a single click, I hide two of them and leave the third one as visible.

I tried also to use a @variable on which to base visibiliies of the SubReports with expressions... but I can' find a way to change the value of this "@variable".
I don't want these textboxes to call back the same report with an additional parameter "ID of the report to be shown this time" because this would mean to activate all the 4 Stored each time I want to change visualization

What's the best way to do this?

Thankx

Comment: This previous question could be useful?  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6279704/how-do-i-set-the-visibility-of-a-text-box-in-ssrs-using-an-expression

Comment: Thankx Steve-o169 but I don't think so as the visibility should dependt on an action of the user, not on the number of column of a Report. From what can I see, the only possible actions are going to a different report or URL

Comment: My point in posting that is that you could have a parameter with default value 1, additional values of 2,3,4 and set visibility based on that parameter.  `=IIF (Parameters!Selected.Value = 1, True, False)` and so on.  So when the parameter changes, it should change the visibility of the report items.  I guess the only issue is that you have to run the report again with the parameter changed.

Comment: Now I see what you mean and yes, I was trying to go along that line: I add this parameter to each of the Stored in such a way that the stored doesnt do any job if invoked with a parameter value that is different from the only one it is related to.
Thank you